# How does Fae of Wishes / Granted work in a THG limited event?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-two-headed-giant

[Fae of Wishes](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=fae%20of%20wishes) can be cast as the adventure Granted, which has the text:

> You may choose a noncreature card you own from outside the game,
>   reveal it, and put it into your hand.

How does this work in a Two-Headed Giant sealed event? Usually cards that do this allow you to search your sideboard, and usually for limited events that would be anything in your card pool that isn't already in your deck. For Two-Headed Giant, though, teams of players share a card pool. So how does this work? I can see several possibilities:

- I can only search for a card from the packs I opened
- I can search for any card from our combined card pool
- Cards in the card pool are divided up between team members before the game starts and each team member can only search for cards in their half.

Answer (score 7):

You can search for any card from the combined pool.

From the Magic Tournament Rules for the [Two-Headed Giant Limited format](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/mtr9-6/):

> Cards not used in a team’s starting decks are considered a shared
>   sideboard by the two players that both players can access.

Answer (score 2):

I know that user3490 has the correct answer, but here is an answer from the comprehensive rule book (my preferred authoritative source for these sorts of questions, when available):

> 100.4c In limited play involving the Two-Headed Giant multiplayer variant, all cards in a team’s card pool but not in either player’s deck are in that team’s sideboard.

So either player could grab a card from the entire pool. My guess is that this rule is practical in nature. As a long-time aficionado of 2HG sealed, I can say that most teams organize all of their cards together, without regard to who opened them.

---

Side-note 1: For other team formats, option 3 is true:

> 100.4d In limited play involving other multiplayer team variants, each card in a team’s card pool but not in any player’s deck is assigned to the sideboard of one of those players. Each player has their own sideboard; cards may not be transferred between players.

Side-note 2: 2HG is usually the preferred abbreviation for Two-Headed Giant.